# Facebook share is not working (Drupal 6)

Tags: social-network

facebook share is not working on my Drupal website which is in Drupal 6 and using php 5.3. Attached is the snapshot of the share button. While sharing the content it is navigating to site search link (I can't attach snapshot of the problem as i am a new user of this website)

Please suggest how to over come from this problem....

Comment: are you using a module or fb share button code? and what happens when you clicked on the share button?

Comment: I am using FB share button code. when i am clicking on share it is taking me to share window of facebook with my site google search link

Comment: are you using this url to share something on fb? `http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=test&p[summary]=rest&p[url]=http://test.com`, if not then test this url.

Comment: Thanks Ahmad sorry actually we are using fbconnect module for the site

Comment: and this is the code node tpl.php page <a expr:share_url='data:post.<?php print $node->path; ?>' href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php' name='fb_share' type='box_count'>Share</a><script src='http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share' type='text/javascript'></script>